# What is a good workflow for java with EJB, JSP, Servlet, and shared project, jQuery in eclipse/glassfish?

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

I am attempting to learn java EE by developing an app from scratch.  What I have now is JSPs, EJBs, Servlets, jQuery script. I feel my progress is very slow right now.

I am afraid to consider JRebel-like tools at the moment.

1. Is there a step by step cycle I can follow to be more efficient?
2. When should I trigger the .reload file?
3. When should I delete/restart glassfish, when I modify: java, jsp, jsp fragment, dependent project?
4. Do I need to restart every time I modify a java file or only on major changes like add/remove class, add/remove method?
5. Do I need to run in debug mode every time so I can immediately see my changes on the fly?

Comment: #1 is too unspecific to address in any meaningful way. The other questions should be asked separately.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I am at a loss trying to figure out how to develop java ee efficiently.  With other frameworks, they are as simple as code > run > stop > repeat.  In java ee, the run and stop part takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

Since your last comment, I think maybe I understand a little better what you're after.

I know you're looking for a glassfish solution, which I don't know very well, but if you're willing to work with other application servers, there are some good solutions for fast turnaround.

The [JBoss IDE](http://www.jboss.org/products/devstudio/download/) is free and integrates tightly with the JBoss Application Server. If you use the default directory layouts created by the Eclipse project wizards, turnaround for most changes is completely transparent and nearly simultaneous. I think you can find other IDEs with similar characteristics. (BTW - I don't use JRebel myself but hear very good reports from those I know who do.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I do plan to learn wildfly in the future, I've actually downloaded it already.  Currently, I have already figured out a workflow to speed up development.  Changes to JSP, js, resources requries re-run, while any(?) change to java requires me to delete the app to undeploy, then rerun my servlet.